# How do I use a python function in my robot framework test suite?

Tags: python, robotframework

I would like to import a python function into my robot framework test suite and then run it. I have imported the library that the function is in and then tried to use it but it doesn't seem to work. How would I utilise the function in the test case?

The function is this

```
class BasicActions:

  def pingtest():
          host = ping('172.16.240.105', count=4, interval=1)
          return  host.address
```

The test suite looks like this

```
***Settings***
Library  utility.BasicActions.BasicActions

***Test Cases***
${pinger}=  utility.BasicActions.BasicActions.pingtest()
```

I know what is in the test case is wrong but I just dont know what to put. Anybody know how to import functions??

Comment: Library  utility.BasicActions.py :it should work otherwise you can go through the article https://medium.com/swlh/robot-framework-creating-custom-keywords-78786caa6f89

Comment: Is this python code is copy-paste from your project or you modified after? Currently it has wrong indentation and missing argument (self). Also error (if any) would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To import a function from a given library, you need to use the `from mymodule import function1` syntax.
Let's take a concrete example with the following imaginary repository:

```
workspace
|---folder1
|     |---module1.py
|---folder2
|     |---file1.py
|---test1.py
```

If your useful function `foo()` is in `module1.py`, and you want to use it in `file1.py`, write `from folder1.module1 import foo` at the beginning of `file1.py`. You can then then use `foo()` in the `file1` code freely.

I don't know if I understood the question correctly but I hope this helps.